# Access to cookies or WebBroswer class from phonegap plugin running windows phone

Tags: cookies, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I have to manage cookies (delete it) from my phonegap app running on a windows phone 8.

I've created a C# phonegap plugin. On the web, I've found that WebBroswer class can be the way to delete the cookies of my webView.

But I cannot find the exact way to access to this class from my phonegap plugin.

The phonegap plugin in windows phone 8 extends the "BaseCommand" phonegap class.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Julien T.

Comment: Hello Julien, were you able to clear/delete cookies from your phonegap app?

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you're looking for: http://github.com/bez4pieci/Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin

Usage:

window.cookies.clear(function() {
    console.log('Cookies cleared!');
});

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm currently unable to add a comment to either the orignal question or the answer by ericpeters0n I'm adding this answer to save time for anyone else reading....

Basically ericpeters0n suggestion is a dead end as the plugin does not support windows phone 8 and therefore does not answer the question

Edit: [How can I clear the cookies in a windows phone 8 cordova plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411264/how-can-i-clear-the-cookies-in-a-windows-phone-8-cordova-plugin/24532567#24532567)